# Compling vlc-android source code

Tags: libvlc

I tried to use vlc player source code for android.I have downloaded the files using git
as mentioned in this link

http://rootzwiki.com/topic/475-compiling-vlc-from-source-for-apk/

After this step "./bootstrap -t arm-eabi -d android", i tried to use "make" command.

I Am getting the the following error while making

```
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/vlc-android/extras/contrib/build-src/ffmpeg'
make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/vlc-android/extras/contrib/build-src/ffmpeg'
make[2]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add `+' to parent make rule.
INSTALL libavdevice/libavdevice.a
INSTALL libavformat/libavformat.a
INSTALL libavcodec/libavcodec.a
INSTALL libpostproc/libpostproc.a
INSTALL libswscale/libswscale.a
INSTALL libavcore/libavcore.a
INSTALL libavutil/libavutil.a
INSTALL libavdevice/avdevice.h
INSTALL libavdevice/libavdevice.pc
INSTALL libavformat/avformat.h
INSTALL libavformat/avio.h
INSTALL libavformat/libavformat.pc
INSTALL libavcodec/avcodec.h
INSTALL libavcodec/avfft.h
INSTALL libavcodec/dxva2.h
INSTALL libavcodec/opt.h
INSTALL libavcodec/vaapi.h
INSTALL libavcodec/vdpau.h
INSTALL libavcodec/xvmc.h
INSTALL libavcodec/libavcodec.pc
INSTALL libpostproc/postprocess.h
INSTALL libpostproc/libpostproc.pc
INSTALL libswscale/swscale.h
INSTALL libswscale/libswscale.pc
INSTALL libavcore/audioconvert.h
INSTALL libavcore/avcore.h
INSTALL libavcore/imgutils.h
INSTALL libavcore/parseutils.h
INSTALL libavcore/samplefmt.h
INSTALL libavcore/libavcore.pc
INSTALL libavutil/adler32.h
INSTALL libavutil/attributes.h
INSTALL libavutil/avassert.h
INSTALL libavutil/avstring.h
INSTALL libavutil/avutil.h
INSTALL libavutil/base64.h
INSTALL libavutil/bswap.h
INSTALL libavutil/common.h
INSTALL libavutil/cpu.h
INSTALL libavutil/crc.h
INSTALL libavutil/error.h
INSTALL libavutil/eval.h
INSTALL libavutil/fifo.h
INSTALL libavutil/file.h
INSTALL libavutil/intfloat_readwrite.h
INSTALL libavutil/intreadwrite.h
INSTALL libavutil/lfg.h
INSTALL libavutil/log.h
INSTALL libavutil/lzo.h
INSTALL libavutil/mathematics.h
INSTALL libavutil/md5.h
INSTALL libavutil/mem.h
INSTALL libavutil/opt.h
INSTALL libavutil/pixdesc.h
INSTALL libavutil/pixfmt.h
INSTALL libavutil/random_seed.h
INSTALL libavutil/rational.h
INSTALL libavutil/sha1.h
INSTALL libavutil/avconfig.h
INSTALL libavutil/libavutil.pc
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/vlc-android/extras/contrib/build-src/ffmpeg'
touch .ffmpeg
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/vlc-android/extras/contrib/build-src'
make: *** [using-src] Error 2
```

Anyone please help..

Comment: http://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile ?